# Compiler related - are these two C codes really identical?

Tags: c, multithreading, compiler-construction, rtos

In a multi-thread or RTOS environment, are these codes below identical?

I believe they are not. But is the 1st code absolute save in a multi-thread environment? Is there a rule for compiler to assign a register for 'ga' and would not read 'ga' again later in func_a()?

I know I can use lock, but this is not a question about how to protect the data. It is just a question about the compiler behaviour.

// ga is a global variable.

```
int func_a() {

    int a = ga;
    return a>2 ? a-2 : 2-a;
}

int func_b() {

    return ga>2 ? ga-2 : 2-ga;
}
```

My intention is looking for a standard way (not platform specific) to read ga only once and assign its value to a local variable 'a'.

'a' can then be used consistently regardless of whether 'ga' has changed.

Comment: Heh!  Good point, but lets assume it is..

Comment: Yes, assume it is preemptive and also ISR may change the 'ga'.

Comment: What threading standard are you using? Is this a Windows threads question? A POSIX threads question? You have all, and only, the guarantees your particular threading standard, compiler, or platform provide. Since you don't tell us any of those three things, all bets are off. It's completely undefined behavior by the C standard, since it never mentions threads.

Comment: From your comments on the answers, I gather that you specifically want to avoid using a lock. *Why* do you want to avoid using a lock?

Comment: If an ISR is changing it, you cannot use a kernel lock to protect it and a very, very good practice indeed is to ensure that all such ISR-communication variables are volatile and that only one thread ever accesses them - one signalled by the ISR upon change just before it exits via the OS to make the signaled thread ready/running.  Try very, very hard to not access such a variable from multiple threads - it is very, very, very difficult to get that right.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to implement a lock free circular buffer--see comments below.
It is a C standard question, not for any specific platform.

Comment: Then the answer is that it cannot be done. Using just the C standard, it is impossible to safely exchange data between threads. You need something beyond the C standard like atomic operations, memory barriers, or the like.

Answer (score 2):

Both these versions of code have undefined behaviour in the face of multiple threads executing the functions. Certainly different compilers can do different things regarding saving the global variable into registers, or not. What's more, there's no guarantee that assigning to a local variable can be done in an atomic way with respect to threads that are mutating the global variable.

Comment: Then what is the reliable way to get a 'snapshot' of a global variable and then play with it without caring about whether its value has been updated or not? - except for using a lock.

Comment: Using a lock works. A specific compiler's implementation of volatile may be do enough to allow atomic reads and writes. But obviously without a lock you will still have races.

Comment: What would happen if this function was passed the address of ga in a parameter and had to dereference it?  Would that change anything?

Comment: That's what locks are for. Why would you not want to use a lock when you have the *precise* problem that locks perfectly solve? If your particular platform provides something else that does the same thing, then you can use it. But why not use a lock?

Comment: I am think about a lock-free circular buffer.
When there is only one consumer and one producer, there should be no need to use a lock.
However, there are also cases where I need to read the head & tail pointers of the circular buffer to get the buffer state (full, empty) etc.
These reads need to get a 'snapshot' of the pointers so that the result would be consistent.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - a driver is updating the thing as well so, no kernel locks.

Comment: @user184258 - in the ISR, move the head pointer up.  In the ONE thread that handles this ISR, move the tail pointer up.  Use a semaphore to signal the thread from the ISR after data has been inserted.  Don't try to read the head pointer in the thread - it's not necessary.  If that thread is signaled and becomes running, there is data to be read at the tail pointer.  The semaphore will keep a count of the number of data items outstanding from the driver.  No polling required, so no issue with volatile, threads, ISR and the global veriable.

Comment: In order to conclude that there "should be no need to use a lock", you have to reason about the specifics of your platform. One can certainly imagine platforms where there is in fact no need to use a lock and one can also imagine platforms where one must use a lock. (For example, consider one where inter-CPU memory visibility was only guaranteed on lock operations.) Since we don't know what platform you are using, we can't help you. This is 100% platform specific. You got the C answer -- it's undefined behavior.

Comment: The ISR may put multiple bytes into the circular buffer.

Comment: Yes, it is a C standard question, not platform specific.

Just looking at Linux source code, would this do the 'thing'?!
/*
 * Prevent the compiler from merging or refetching accesses.  The compiler
 * is also forbidden from reordering successive instances of ACCESS_ONCE(),
 * but only when the compiler is aware of some particular ordering. ........  */


#define ACCESS_ONCE(x) (*(volatile typeof(x) *)&(x))

Comment: @user184258 - hence use a semaphore to signal ONE thread. A more efficient solution is possible if you have some protocol where the ISR can assemble a protocol unit on its own and insert a complete PDU onto the queue and only then signal the semaphore.  That saves a lot of signaling overhead.

Comment: I think int a = ACCESS_ONCE(ga); does the trick and it seems to be a standard use of volatile, so should all compilers support it?

Comment: No. Any use of `volatile` in relation to threads in C is platform-specific (or threading model specific). If you look in the C standard, the only standard you can look to, it says nothing about how `volatile` works with threads. If your platform requires something to make this work with threads, nothing requires `volatile` to provide it.

Comment: The only intention is to get a copy of ga and assign it to a local variable, 'a'.

It doesn't matter whether or not ga would be changed by other threads while I am using 'a' later on.

In my example func_a(), by using ACCESS_ONCE(), it can guarantee that 'return a>2 ? a-2 : 2-a;' has a consistent result, i.e. would not return a negative value, which would otherwise do without using ACCESS_ONCE().

Comment: You stated that you do not want to assume more than the C standard guarantees. If you really mean that, then `volatile` provides no thread related guarantees.

Comment: Do you think int a = (*(volatile int *)&(ga)); return a>2 ? a-2 : 2-a; can return negative value?

Comment: According to the C standard, there's no guarantee that it will not

Comment: My understanding is 'a' will get a value of 'ga' only once (whether it is a new or old value, that doesn't really matter) and the following calculation will only access 'a', not 'ga' any more.
This will guarantee returning a positive value.

Comment: An interesting comment from Linus about using of ACCESS_ONCE: http://yarchive.net/comp/linux/ACCESS_ONCE.html
-- "We have ACCESS_ONCE() as a macro to guarantee that the compiler doesn't rematerialize a pointer access. That also would clarify the fact that we access something unsafe outside a lock."

Comment: @user184258 Linux is not built with standard C.

Comment: @user184258 That's because `ACCESS_ONCE` is platform-specific and compiler-specific. As has been repeated many times, no use of `volatile` in conjunction with threads can possibly be pure C since in pure C, there are no threads.

Comment: Please move extended discussions to [chat].

Answer (score 2):

There is no rule in the C standard that requires the compiler to implement those functions differently. e.g. When working with registers, the compiler may or may not 'optimize out' the assignment from `ga` to `a` (i.e. By 'optimize out', I mean: load `ga` into a REG, then use the same REG to do the rest of the computation, using it as `a`). Or it may not do so.

If you want to implement a lock-free data structure:

1. C99 offers nothing that can help you.
2. [C11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (very recent standard) offers you atomic data types.

If you are using C99, then you either need to:

1. Use locks (and hence, not lock-free code)
2. Be ready to write architecture specific code. The least you need to do is use a minimal set of atomic operations, as done in [this library](http://www.liblfds.org/) that implements lock-free data structures using atomic operations provided by the x86, x86_64, and ARM ISAs.

In an earlier version of this answer, I touched upon a *side issue* (which has to do with `volatile`, and which is really not relevant to your *real* question):

There is one case that can put a restriction on how `func_b` is implemented, but I am actually going off on a tangent here: If `ga` is declared as a `volatile`.

If `ga` is volatile, then each read on `ga` *must* load `ga` from memory afresh. i.e. in `func_b`, `ga` will be loaded from memory two times. Once for the comparison, and once to calculate the return value. The expected use is, for example say `ga` refers to a memory mapped I/O port. Then if value of `ga` changes in between the two reads, this will reflect in the return value. However, if you change `ga` in another thread, don't expect sane/defined behavior.

On the other hand, *not* having a `volatile` qualifier does not mean that `ga` will be read exactly once in `func_b`. And there is no qualifier that is the 'opposite of volatile'.

Comment: I understand the use of volatile. My question is more about the opposite of what 'volatile' intends to achieve.
I want to read 'ga' only once and use its value afterwards without reading it again, in order not to get inconsistent result (i.e. a>2 ? a-2 : 2-a)

Comment: @user184258: There's absolutely no guarantee in whether your compiled code will have one read of ga or many and whether that read will be atomic. Sorry, the language standard does not guarantee you anything here. This may work as you want on some CPUs and with some compilers, but doesn't have to and on other CPUs and with other compilers won't.

Comment: @Alex +1. Right. Also: I edited the answer to clarify that 'not having volatile' does not guarantee a single read.

Answer (score 0):

the behaviour depends on which compiler you're using, every compiler has its own rules regarding the optimisation.

Comment: There can be hardware-specific behavior as well, not just compiler-specific.

Answer (score 0):

The two snippets are likely going to end up with identical machine code. Neither of them is safe in a multi-thread case.

`volatile` would force the creation of a temporary variable, but since the copy from "ga" into the volatile variable is not guaranteed to be atomic, this is not thread-safe.

The only safe way to write such code is with guards:

```
int func_a() {

    mtx_lock(&ga_mutex);
    int a = ga;
    mtx_unlock(&ga_mutex);

    return a>2 ? a-2 : 2-a;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't ga still need to be volatile? How would the compiler now that it can't move its read to before/after mutex operations?

Comment: @Alex No, `ga` doesn't need to be volatile. The compiler could know it many ways, but it's not your problem, it's the problem of whoever designed the mutex operations and whoever built the compiler. It *must* know somehow, otherwise the mutex operations are broken. (One way it's commonly done is with a special compiler intrinsic built into the mutex invocations, called a [clobber](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html#ss5.3). On some platforms, it "just works" because the compiler can't assume the mutex operations themselves don't modify `ga`. It's platform-specific.)

Comment: @Alex Compilers may change the order in which the code is executed, if it can prove that the order does not affect the result. It may do such optimizations to give better instruction piping, branch prediction and so on. In a multi-threaded, multi-core environment, such optimizations can be dangerous, if one core makes assumptions and decides to cache instructions before the code is executed, then the other core modifies the value. To prevent bugs like that, the concept of [memory barriers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier) must be used. (continued ->)

Comment: @Alex In some instances, the compiler implements memory barriers through the volatile keyword, but this is not guaranteed. Some compilers/OS implement memory barriers together with the mutex locks (I believe this is most common). There is no standard for it.